# Conditional return type of function, handling the returns

Tags: typescript

so I made a function that maps links that are coming from a CMS, but sometimes the link in the CMS can be optional, and so in that case I want to return `null`, but when they are required `null` can't be a return type, so I used conditional types with ternary operator and created this function:

```
export const mapLink = <T = true>({
  cached_url,
  url,
  target,
  linktype,
  ...props
}: ISbLink): T extends false ? LinkProps | null : LinkProps => {
  console.log({ cached_url, url, target, linktype, ...props });
  if (!cached_url && !url) return null;

  let href = "";

  if (linktype === "url") href = url;

  if (linktype === "story") href = cached_url === "home" ? "/" : cached_url;

  return {
    href,
    target: target || "_self"
  };
};
```

The function works fine except that I get this error:

`Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'T extends false ? InternalLinkProps | null : InternalLinkProps'`

On line `if (!cached_url && !url) return null;`

You can see the error and the usage in the playground here: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUBGAZUBrZAbwChlkFEALCAEwH0BXKAGwC5kBnMKUAcwG5SyGMAjMaYAJ4AHCOwBEAWwbMwwZvnmCywGuy48QAoRpB4pshVwD2USfOQAfZPKbMtQt-u59tyMHBQvBBgCnQcYjAOzvJ0mMxwZh4AvsTEoJCwiCi4ZgAKUNbSHERCZJRQEDDehrwANGX%20gcGhLuGR0W3xiXjyxKnECNYgXMiKcNK5BAC8yAA8ACrIs9wMEAB8ABQkZBQI1PRuDWRHQgFBIcfIpuYyEP3sGDj4AJTsSxAAHpAgNCXwzAiyAA-MgpgUiiVnCAVMxkOxwYVist1qUdDBkJsAIR7A6MFjIABkhOQWLcL2QlTATBAyBhzGYghMIWQFSqyxcHiEwAxmxuFhQ0yFLjc8gpbIxszcTPRmP5d2WwvkNjsYtZlUl5CotHxcKFs3klGsiggDlB8gA9A52LiddK0mQqTS0WR1VUrmRzi12F6WY4Yu1mFEhMlBKG0sQLRbkAwOHBgoNhqNKgBHBjASo0KaPLBTDk7V22w4sBRGk3yD3CUTiAUKZSqdSaSu6BQVxryywuFX2Su%201qxCJBtuumMlzn9NJDEZgZBFNTDODMbNoXP4fONIu61uVkRiCR3OsqNQ3YeulucysduQilinz3NEJhbpJSteccDKejcbSWQ0ABKEBphmtB5rM35TJsqbppmUwvJOSYzt%20v4APLSPOICLqBYwTFMcwAhEWxzsAC5Lq8QA)

How can I handle that error?

Comment: See [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912); without support for generic control flow analysis, you'll have to work around the issue.  You could use an assertion as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WzGnkw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use function overloading is easier in this case:

```
function mapLink<T extends true>(isBlink: ISbLink): LinkProps;
function mapLink<T extends false>(isBlink: ISbLink): LinkProps | null;
function mapLink({
  cached_url,
  url,
  target,
  linktype
}: ISbLink): LinkProps | null {
  if (!cached_url && !url) return null;

  let href = "";

  if (linktype === "url") href = url;

  if (linktype === "story") href = cached_url === "home" ? "/" : cached_url;

  return {
    href,
    target: target || "_self"
  };
};


const mappedRequiredLink = mapLink(requiredLink); // LinkProps

const mappedOptionalLink = mapLink<false>(optionalLink); // LinkProps | null
```

Comment: This is not a class, so this gives a duplicate name identifier issue

Comment: It should works if the function is declare with `function` instead of a `const` variable